# How can I update the pulse generator block

Tags: matlab, block, simulink

I have a question, 
I want to use "Pulse Generator" block to generate square wave form. Then I want to change the phase of the square wave externally. As you know, the phase delay in this block can be adjusted internally. 
Please let me know how I can update this block in order to connect an input signal which sets the phase of the output signal?

Thanks
Foad

Comment: What is the software you are using?

Comment: Matlab simulink 2012a

Comment: You should tag your question with `matlab` then like I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The Pulse Generator block does not give the user the ability to input any of its parameters as signals.  You'll need to create your own block, either using a combination of other appropriate blocks or as an S-Function, to give the functionality that you require.

A starting point for the S-Function approach can be found [here](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-sfunction-square-wave-with-jitter.html).  You'll need to modify it so that the phase is passed in as an input and then determines the correct output based on that input.